# How to make a vector of character strings using strsplit in R?

Tags: r, split, string-parsing, strsplit

I have a block of text that I have scraped into R and is being read as one long character string.

Example of block of text:

```
[1] "abc \n 18:19 \n abc \n 7-9 \n abc \n"
```

Summary of block of text:

```
summary(text)
Length       Class       Mode
     1   character  character
```

I then do a strsplit `text <- strsplit(text, "\n")`

Summary of text after `strsplit`

```
summary(text)
      Length    Class        Mode
[1,]  5         -none-  character
```

What I would like when I complete the `strsplit`

```
summary(text)
Length      Class       Mode
     5  character  character
```

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if anymore information is needed.

Comment: you need to escape `\n` by doing `\\n`. Try it

Comment: `summary` is an unusual/wrong approach to investigating an object's structure. Try `str` or `class` or just typing the object's name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `strsplit()` is a `list()` of character:

```
mytext <- "abc \n 18:19 \n abc \n 7-9 \n abc \n"
text <- strsplit(mytext, "\n")
class(text)
[1] "list"
```

Each element of the list is of class `character`

```
summary(text[[1]])
Length     Class      Mode 
     5 character character
```

To convert the list to a vector you can `unlist()` it:

```
text=unlist(text)
summary(text)
   Length     Class      Mode 
        5 character character
```

Comment: Do you mean `strsplit(text`?

Answer (score 2):

Other option would be to `scan` the string to a `vector` directly

```
 summary(scan(text=text, what='', quiet=TRUE))
 #   Length     Class      Mode 
 #        5 character character
```